# In the end / at the end/ at the beginning

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I need some help with this question from an English test for English learners :

Fill with the correct word:

> ____ of the play, everybody stood up and applauded. ____, it was a good play.
>
> A. in the end - in the end
> B. At the end- in the end
> C. At the beginning - at the end
> D. In the end - At the beginning

I would choose letter "B" and I would like to know if you guys agree with me. also I would like to know  this is also possible:

> At the end of the play, everybody stood up and applauded. **At the beginning**, it was a good play.

I can use the bold expression without of?

Comment: You are almost certainly correct in terms of what a standardized test would want from you.  What exactly is the context here, though?  Just answering an obvious test question?

Comment: There is no context here, it is just this question, exactly at this way. So you agree that , letter B is the correct answer?

Comment: As @SouthpawHare said, you are correct.  Further, your suggested phrase is technically correct, but doesn't make a lot of sense as written.  The implication is that the play started good, then got worse...but then why would everyone stand and applaud at the end?

Answer (score 1):

**At the end** of the play, everybody stood up and applauded. **In the end**, it was a good play.

Yes, "At the beginning" can be used without "of".

"At" is appropriate when there is a more specific reference point in time. "In" is less specific.

Here is a biblical reference where the specific point in time is not relevant or known:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

Comment: thanks a lot!Do you have an example of a sentence that I can use "at the beginning"without "of" ? The meaning would be changed?

Thanks

Comment: At the beginning (of the play), everybody was having a good time. You can remove "of the play". However the context becomes important here. It must be clear that you're talking about the play.

Comment: "At the beginning, it was a good play.  Unfortunately, it quickly lost steam after the half-way point."